# How to write COUNT and DISTINCT from same table with different WHERE in one SQL?

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

Hi I would like to write one SQL statement that returns both the count and count(distinct) from the same table but with different WHERE clause.

e.g.

```
People
-----------------------
ID      Name        Sex
1       Alex        F
2       Alex        M
3       Alex        M
4       Andy        F
5       Andy        M
6       Ann         F
7       Ann         F
```

In this example, I can write `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People), (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM People)`, but thats just too many SELECT. So I write `SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM People` instead.

But what if I would like to return something like `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People), (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM People WHERE Sex='M')`. How do you do the same like above to have less SELECT?

I don't know if this is related, I know that I can write something like `SELECT COUNT(1), SUM(CASE WHEN Sex='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM People` to have different WHERE clauses in one SELECT, but thats only for COUNT, it doesn't handle DISTINCT. How do you use this when DISTINCT is needed?

The DB is SQL Server 2008 R2, Thank you

Comment: What is the desired output from the table `people` of the sample data you posted in your query?

Comment: I'm interested to know why you specifically need to reduce the number of SELECT statements? Do you have a performance problem using multiple statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select count(id), count(distinct case when sex = 'M' then name else null end)
From people
```

You can see it in SQL fiddle here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22fb2/9/0)

Comment: This works because it is counting the distinct names but the name is null when the gender is not male and thus drops out of the aggregate expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show results of two grouping operations, so union can help you:

```
SELECT 'Full' AS 'Grouping Type', count(*) AS 'Count' FROM people
UNION
SELECT 'Men', count(DISTINCT name) FROM people WHERE sex = 'M'
```

Comment: Yes, but here you don't reduce the SELECTs to just one and you get two rows instead of one.

Comment: I know, but don't see the requirement to show just one row. And actually don't see the reason of using one row for such kind of data.

Comment: I want that to be in one row because I want to generate a report, which contains many other similar tables (UNION). So one row for one table.